# Instead of line numbers GCC prints cc1

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

When I compile a program gcc gives me gcc instead of the line numbers, making it very difficult to pinpoint errors!
What is wrong?

`test.c` contains:

```
#include "bgraph_utils.h"

int main(){
    g
}
```

`bgraph_utils.h` contains:

```
#include "bgraph_rep.h"
```

`bgraph_rep.h` contains:

```
#include "dll_list.h"
```

`dll_list.h` is blank

each header had other definitions, but I have left them out for succinctness

When compiling using: `gcc tets.c`, get the error:

```
In function ‘main’:
cc1: error: ‘g’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cc1: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
cc1: error: for each function it appears in.)
cc1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
```

if Just including `bgraph_rep.h` in `test.c`, line numbers are outputted correctly.

Comment: Post an example of the output?

Comment: Example program, example command-line, and example output, please!

Comment: probably an error during the linking stage.

Comment: @lijie, usually linker errors are prefaced with `ld`, which is the usual name of the linker and not with `cc1`, which is the name of the compiler.

Comment: @carl: sorry yes you are right

Comment: My version of gcc (version 4.4.5) does not exhibit the behaviour you describe. What version are you using?

Comment: My version of gcc (4.3.4) does not exhibit the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only time `gcc` gives me an error starting with `cc1` is when I pass it a bad flag:

```
$ gcc -abadflag file.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-abadflag"
```

Is that what's happening to you?

Comment: No, seems to be when I add a certain self defined header. The header is fine, I even just put some token definitions in there. Still does that